# Locking UISearchBar on top of TableView

Tags: iphone, ios, tableview, searchbar

I wanted to lock search bar on top of table view when y boundary reaches 0 ( or beyond - value)

I tried to in scroll view delegate method, but nothing really changed. In fact, the search bar's frame changed, but it still behaved as default.

Any ideas?

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
   UISearchBar *searchBar = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar;
   CGRect rect = searchBar.frame;
   rect.origin.y = MAX(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y);

   self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0,MAX(0,scrollView.contentOffset.y),320,44);
}
```

Comment: Probably, you can separate your search bar from the table view. Add a search bar on the top of the content view and place a table view below that search bar.

Comment: Well, that's obvious. I just wanna know why it doesn't work even though frame itself has been changed.

Answer (score 1):

In your viewdidload method you need to offset the table view:

```
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, 44.0);
```

Then In IB drag a searchbar above your UITableview in your UINavigation controller
Or prgrammically add it.

Comment: It's not what I want. Setting offset is nothing more than just hiding search bar.

Comment: @REALFREE then when you pull the table down the search bar also comesdown

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setNeedsLayout` if you're running on iOS 6.0+.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
   UISearchBar *searchBar = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar;
   CGRect rect = searchBar.frame;
   rect.origin.y = MAX(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
   [scrollView setNeedsLayout];                  // <-- Call setNeedsLayout here.
   self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0,MAX(0,scrollView.contentOffset.y),320,44);
}
```